# Add a Class to an anchor link

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, hyperlink

I have this code to add the class:

```
(Master.FindControl("ControlName")).Attributes.Add("class", "menu-selected");
```

But this doesn't work for the link:

```
<a href="Default.aspx" id="mnuHome" runat="server">Home</a>
```

But throws the error:

> 'System.Web.UI.Control' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Attributes'
>   and no extension method 'Attributes'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

I could turn all my links into Hyperlink server controls but this gets really messy, I'd rather keep it like this if possible.  Is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast your control:

```
((HtmlAnchor)(Master.FindControl("ControlName"))).Attributes.Add("class", "menu-selected");
```

**UPDATE**
It is `HtmlAnchor`, not the previously state `HtmlGenericControl`.